# How should I host a .Net Core Console application that needs to run 24/7?

Tags: docker, windows-services, containers, web-hosting

My application is written in .Net Core as a Console App. It consumes a RabbitMQ Queue and it listens on SignalR sockets, calls 3rd party APIs and publishes to RabbitMQ Queues. It needs to run 24/7.

This is all working great on my local environment, but now I am ready to deploy to a web server, I am trying to work out how best to host this application. I am leaning towards deploying into a Docker container, but I am unsure if this is advisable for a 24/7 application.

Are containers designed for short lived workers only, and will they be costly to leave running all the time?

Can I put my container on my Web Server alongside my Web APIs etc. and host on the same Windows EC2 box maybe to save hosting costs?

How would others approach the deployment of this .Net Core application onto a web hosting environment?

Comment: We use Azure webapps with webjobs, but the main application is the web app; the webjob is just a small thing that consumes an RMQ. Do also note that SO is not intended for “recommend me a book, tutorial, library, service..” requests so your question probably won’t attract any reasonable (not opinion based) answers and may be closed as off topic

Comment: Thanks, I tried to get a response on Stack Exchange but got no replies, hence I'm posting here to try and get some advice.

Comment: Thanks @CaiusJard - Web Jobs is something I will start looking into.. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/03/07/how-to-deploy-a-net-core-console-application-to-azure-webjob/

Answer (score 0):

Does you application maintain any state ? You can have a long live application but you’ll want to handle state if you maintain it . Might be able to use a compose file to handle everything like volumes , networking, and restart policies .

Comment: Yes it has dictionaries that store the state of the application. I plan, every time the state changes, to save the data to disk or DB so that it can be recovered after failure.